# How to convert binary to hex in Batch or Powershell?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, binary, hex

I wondering if there is a way to convert binary to hexadecimal, in Batch or Powershell language.

```
Exemple :
10000100 to 84
01010101 to 55
101111111111 to BFF
```

In a simple way, I’m not very good in Batch or Powershell.

I will appreciate any kind of information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting a binary string to an integer is pretty straightforward:

```
$number = [Convert]::ToInt32('10000100', 2)
```

Now we just need to convert it to hexadecimal:

```
$number.ToString('X')
```

or

```
'{0:X}' -f $number
```

Answer (score 0):

(pure batch)

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
CALL :CONVERT 10000100
CALL :CONVERT 101111111111
CALL :CONVERT 1111111111
GOTO :EOF

:: Convert %1 to hex
:CONVERT
SET "data=%1"
SET "result="

:cvtlp
:: If there are no characters left in `data` we are finished
IF NOT DEFINED data ECHO %1 ----^> %result%&GOTO :EOF 

:: Get the last 4 characters of `data` and prefix with "000"
:: This way, if there are only say 2 characters left (xx), the result will be
:: 000xx. we then use the last 4 characters only
=
SET "hex4=000%data:~-4%"
SET "hex4=%hex4:~-4%"

:: remove last 4 characters from `data`

SET "data=%data:~0,-4%"
:: now convert to hex

FOR %%a IN (0 0000 1 0001 2 0010 3 0011 4 0100 5 0101 6 0110 7 0111
            8 1000 9 1001 A 1010 B 1011 C 1010 D 1101 E 1110 F 1111
) DO IF "%%a"=="%hex4%" (GOTO found) ELSE (SET "hex4=%%a")
:found
SET "result=%hex4%%result%"
GOTO cvtlp
```

This solution uses a parsing trick in the `for %%a` loop. The *original* value of `hex4` is compared in the `if` and where the `if` fails, the value tested is assigned to `hex4` so that when a match is found, the previous value tested remains in `hex4`.